# Tabs in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3

how to put tabs in application using only actionscript, there are lot of examples there using flex mx controls for tabnavigator, but i want to use only actionscript or flashscript, please help

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/flash/astra-flash/tabbar/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are many ways you could achieve this with AS3. Try to break it down in terms of functionality, then in terms of display.

From the functionality point of view, you don't have much more than a menu and a set of DisplayObjects.

Most of your efforts will be spent on the view, where the main challenge is simply to frame your selected tab and content so that they appear to be on the same page.

Edit:
You could use a CustomEvent to carry your forms data, each time you move to the next tab , dispatch an Event with the updated values.

```
     // Pseudo Code
     function tabClickHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
     {
         currentForm.validate();
         ++currentTabIndex;

         if( currentForm.valid )
         {
              var data:Object = currentForm.data;
              dispatchEvent( new CustomEvent( data ));

         }
     }
```

Comment: HI, i am new developer to ActionScript, i want to develop a tabnavigator. Each tab will contain different forms, and i need to submit all the tabs at the last tab. so i need to catch all the values in all tabs. i have designed using buttons and event listeners.But coming to the last tab i need to catch the form fields there, i couldn't done it,Can anyone help me with the solution and some simple tab navigator code should pass the variables to last tab ?

please Help ?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to roll your own, but it's really easy. If the number of tabs is to be static, I would recommend doing the tab design/layout in the Flash IDE. Make a container symbol and a tab symbol, then repeat the tab symbol horizontally inside the container symbol. Give each tab instance a logical name like "tab1", "tab2", etc. In code, you can instantiate the container symbol and add listeners to each tab like so:

```
var tabContainer:MovieClip = new TabContainer();
addChild(tabContainer);
tabContainer.tab1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tab1_clickHandler);
tabContainer.tab2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, tab2_clickHandler);
```

In the handler for each is where you would be setting what view appears under the container.

If the number of tabs needs to be dynamic, then you will have other architectural considerations I wont go into, but suffice to say, you would use a layout algorithm to place each new tab after that last tab's x + width, and map tab order (childIndex inside the tab container) to view index (perhaps an index in an array of views)